# Responsive Nav that changes image on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, sprite

im creating a responsive site and im trying to get my navigation to alter the header background image on hover, basically, when the page is opened the image is a straight line and when you hover over the link an icon appears on the line over the text, hopefully it will look something like this:

!(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29163680/Screen%20shot%202013-10-17%20at%203.00.51%20PM.png)

I have found a few hover techniques but nothing that will work responsively, any solutions would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

This is what I have so far for the code, which is not very semantic or responsive

HTML

```
<body>


<a href=""
onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image2.src;" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image1.src">PORTFOLIO</a>

<a href=""
onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image3.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image1.src">ABOUT</a>

<a href=""
onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image4.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image1.src">ABOUT</a>

<a href=""
onMouseover="document.imagename.src=image5.src" onMouseout="document.imagename.src=image1.src">ABOUT</a>


<img src="images/head1.png" name="imagename" border="0">
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
if (document.images) {
image1 = new Image
image2 = new Image
image3 = new Image
image4 = new Image
image5 = new Image


image1.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29163680/head1.png"
image2.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29163680/head2.png"
image3.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29163680/head3.png"
image4.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29163680/head4.png"
image5.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29163680/head5.png"

}
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Please, start with showing us what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
<img id="header" src="http://example.com/default.jpg">
<ul>
   <li class="nav-item" data-headerimg="http://example.com/home.jpg"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" data-headerimg="http://example.com/street.jpg"><a href="street.html">Street</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
   $('.nav-item').mouseenter(function() {
      var img = $(this).attr('data-headerimg'); 
      $('img#header').attr('src', img);
   }).mouseleave(function() {
      $('img#header').attr('src', 'http://example.com/default.jpg');
   });
</script>
```

**Update:**

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxHKi

Comment: thnx Azamat! my javascript is limited but I sort of understand whats happening here, the only thing is when I tested it I can't see any images, only the list bullet points? :)

Comment: @user2892088 , I have updated code, I missed `src` on `img` tag. Now you should have default image loaded on page load. I also updated jQuery code to change image back to default one. See if it is what you need ;)

Comment: great, thnx. for some reason I still cant see the images? I posted a version I tried earlier above as well, let me know what you think? :)

Comment: awesome! thnx azamat, your the best! =^J